# How do you circumvent multi-touch?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, multi-touch

I am encountering an issue using pointerdown & pointerup, specifically when it comes to multi-touch devices. While these eventlisteners work as expect with a singular mouse click, touch screens can allow multiple taps simultaneously breaks the following code:

**HTML**

```
 <progress id="air" max="100" value="100">AIR</progress>
```

**JS**

```
 var air = document.querySelector('#air')
 var losingairInterval, gainingairInterval;
        
function drowning() {
  if (air.value <= 0) {
    clearInterval(losingairInterval)
  } else {
    air.value--;
  }
}

// Breathing Mechanic
function gainingair() {
  if (air.value == 100) {
    clearInterval(gainingairInterval)
  } else {
    air.value++;
  }
}

function crouchingdown() {
  clearInterval(gainingairInterval)
  losingairInterval = setInterval(drowning, 100)
}

function crouchingup() {
  clearInterval(losingairInterval)
  gainingairInterval = setInterval(gainingair, 200)
}

addEventListener('pointerup', crouchingup);
addEventListener('pointerdown', crouchingdown);
```

jsFiddle Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/CamWhiting/krufx5by/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than disabling multi-touch, you can detect a set number of pointerup-s or pointerdown-s using a simple IF statement.

```
 // Method to stop multi-touch affecting up the breathing mechanic 
 var killmulti = 0;


// Breathing Mechanic
function gainingair() {
  if (air.value == 100) {
    clearInterval(gainingairInterval)
  } else {
    air.value++;
  }
}

function crouchingdown() {
  killmulti++;
  if (killmulti === 1) {
    clearInterval(gainingairInterval)
    losingairInterval = setInterval(drowning, 100)
  }
}

function crouchingup() {
  killmulti--;
   if (killmulti < 1) {
     clearInterval(losingairInterval)
     gainingairInterval = setInterval(gainingair, 200)
   }

}

addEventListener('pointerup', crouchingup);
addEventListener('pointerdown', crouchingdown);
```